# Creating users in ASP.NET using ASPNETDB and CreateUserWizard giving error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, aspnetdb

I am trying to create users from ASP.NET via ASPNETDB database.

First, I created ASPNETDB using "aspnet_regsql.exe". Then I created an ASP.NET page that has only one control - a `CreateUserWizard` control.

Then I created an "aspnetdb.mdf" file in App_Data folder.

At run time, after entering all the fields, when I clicked on the create user button, it returns the following error:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\ankit\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf".
>   Operating system error 32: "32(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105)". An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\ankit\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Please provide some assistance, as I am new to this. Also, some links having examples of how to use the Membership API to create, authenticate and authorize users and using ASPNETDB?

and the web.config

```
<connectionStrings> 
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=BLR-WS-180;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: please write and your web.config the part that connect to the database, and the part of the authentication.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=BLR-WS-180;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Above is the connection string